# how set a foreign key using data from other sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have some problem using ms-excel, because I want to set a foreign key using other sheet data. I have tried using vlookup but it return `#VALUE!`

So here's example of my data:

Sheet 1

```
Key data1   data2
    john    doe
    alex    sanchez
    will    smith
```

Sheet 2

```
Key data1   data2
1   alex    sanchez
2   john    doe
3   will    smith
```

The result that I expected:

Sheet 1

```
Key data1   data2
2   john    doe
1   alex    sanchez
3   will    smith
```

Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your combination of Data 1 and data 2 is unique to each key, you can concatenate the 2 to create an extra key to back fill the key value.

```
=CONCATENATE(B2,C2)
```

Comment: You'd probably want to separate them in some way: `B2&"_"&C2` or something. Otherwise an ambiguity could arise when you're working with multi-digit numbers.

Comment: so how if the data value is text?

Comment: Great suggestion from @jsheeran. It works the same way even if the data is text value.